# How does a voltage surge/spike affect the wall wart power supply's secondary side?

Tags: power-supply, power, protection, spike, surge

[image]

In the photo, you can observe an old-style adjustable wall wart AC to DC power supply, typically composed of a primary winding, secondary winding, rectifier, and capacitor. If a voltage surge or spike penetrates the wall wart's primary winding, how does it impact the secondary winding and subsequently the device it is connected to? Will the voltage surge on the primary winding induce a surge in the secondary winding, potentially flowing toward the connected device, or will it be mitigated before reaching the device?

Comment: Yes. A surge at the input will cause a surge also at the output because no regulator (surge should be "partially" absorbed by the inside capacitor ... if it does no "blow" ...)

Comment: You may find this analysis relevant: https://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/699195/311631

Comment: @Antonio51 That is a regulated supply so what you said does not apply.

Comment: @Justme Are you sure that the chosen voltages are regulated? I think that they are chosen by switching some "windings" ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In a perfectly coupled transformer, the emf induced in the secondary is proportional to the emf induced in the primary, and the ratio between the two is determined by the ratio of the secondary turns to the primary turns. If one neglects the resistance of the wire in the primary, the terminal voltage of the primary is the same as the emf induced in the primary. There can be a large primary current, a small primary current. It doesn't matter. As long as the transformer is perfectly coupled, the ratio between primary induced voltage and secondary induced voltage is fixed.

However, the tight coupling between a transformer's primary and secondary is largely the due to the core of the transformer. During a voltage surge, the current in the primary is increased. This results in an increase in the magnetic field strength (H) in the core. If the magnetic field strength is increased enough, the core will saturate (i.e. an increase in H no longer results in a correspondingly sized increase in B) and the coupling between the transformer's primary and secondary will drop. Dramatically.

How much may magnetic field strength in a transformer increase before saturation? That depends. Audio transformers are designed to handle a wide range of signal amplitudes. The magnetic field strength in the core, at the peak of a cycle, is often well below the level that would cause saturation. However, mains connected power supply transformers are usually chosen which will saturate at AC voltages not much higher than the mains AC voltage. It is simply a question of economics. Magnetic core and copper wire are expensive.

What does all this have to do with voltage surges? When a power supply transformer receives a voltage surge, some of the surge reaches the secondary. This voltage may be sufficient to damage electronic components. However, unless the surge is small enough, the transformer core will become saturated. At that point, the secondary voltage will actually **fall**. The core will have become saturated, and the coupling between primary and secondary will have become drastically reduced.

This of course assumes that the voltage surge is not so great as to cause arcing or insulation break down between the the primary and secondary coils. If lightning strikes, the transformer core may saturate, but a high voltage will nevertheless reach the secondary -- but not through transformer action, but through the insulation!

While the saturation of the transformer core protects the secondary circuit to some extent, it means that the emf induced in the primary is smaller as well. Since the terminal voltage in the primary is larger, but the induced emf is smaller, the current in the primary may increase catastrophically. The insulation in the primary may be damaged, or in extreme cases, the wire may become fused. Either of these will wreck the transformer.

If the voltage surge is short, i.e. a voltage *spike*, and the transformer has a load connected to the secondary, then another effect is also present. The leakage inductance on the secondary side of the transformer, together with the load and any smoothing capacitors form a low pass filter. Because a spike consists mostly of high frequency components, this low pass filter will attenuate the spike. Again, there is no guarantee that the spike, even as attenuated, won't cause damage.

The effect of the smoothing capacitor on a voltage surge is also not quite intuitive. As mentioned, a surge may initially causes the secondary voltage to rise, but then to go down. To the extent that the smoothing capacitor follows the voltage of the transformer secondary terminal voltage, *well* it follows that voltage. But in following that voltage rise, it must also draw extra current. This extra current will cause increased voltage drops in the transformer secondary coil, and also in the rectifier diodes. This extra voltage drop will mean that the capacitor's terminal voltage will NOT follow the induced emf of the transformer as closely, but will have a lower surge voltage. However, the capacitors will hold whatever surge voltage they do get until the charge in them drains (mainly through the load). Thus, large smoothing capacitors can actually have the effect of prolonging a voltage surge beyond what smaller capacitors might do.

Answer (score 1):

The voltage surge will pass through the transformer, the output of a transformer depends on the rate of change of input current and a spike will result in a very fast change. It will be attenuated a little, the transformer is an inductor which is resistant to changes in current.

The rectifier will not help at all except that it may fail due to over-voltage or current.

The smoothing capacitor will help attenuate the spike.

In conclusion the spike will pass through the power supply, it will be attenuated but probably not enough to provide any significant protection.